# Is 35 minutes' layover time at Delhi enough for a domestic flight?

Tags: air-travel, transit, short-connections, del

I am going to Guwahati from Bangalore, and I have layover time of 35 minutes at DEL. Will that be enough time?

Comment: I fear it will not be enough in any airport, but as I have never been in Delhi I might be wrong. Can you please edit and add details like the companies you fly with and whether you have bought your tickets in one go.

Comment: Minimum time given by airlines to catch a connecting flight with layover time of only 35 minutes....
4m pune >delhi>guwahati #jetairways

Comment: @Willeke at least MUC is very proud of its 30 minutes MCT so yes there are *some* airports where it is enough.

Comment: @chx as long as the flight is in on time, not late. And just a few minutes will be enough to upset the system with such a short connection time.

Answer (score 8):

**If you are flying Jet Airways or JetKonnect, perhaps.**

The only cases at Delhi on domestic-domestic that allow less than 35 minutes are Jet Airways to Jet Airways, JetKonnect to JetKonnect, and between Jet Airways and JetKonnect (formerly known as Jetlite). These allow 30 minutes, which leaves little margin for error in your connection.

If you are doing this offline (across separate tickets), you should have a back up plan in case you miss the flight and need to buy a replacement ticket. If you are on one ticket you will be reaccommodated on a later service, but if it is essential that you are on time, you should investigate other options.

The full Minimum Connect Time information for domestic-to-domestic at Delhi is below. Jet Airways has the code 9W and JetKonnect uses 2K. Times are given in hours:minutes format. DD is short for domestic-domestic.

```
STANDARD.D/D...D/I...I/D...I/I.
ONLINE   1.30  3.00  3.00  1.30
OFFLINE  1.30  3.00  3.00  1.30
** OR * ARE ALL
AI-AI DD  1.00 FLT   10 -   99 - FLT   10 -   99 
AI-AI DD  1.00 FLT   10 -   99 - FLT  100 -  399 
AI-AI DD  1.00 FLT   10 -   99 - FLT  900 -  999 
AI-AI DD  1.15 FLT   10 -  399 - FLT  400 -  899 
AI-AI DD  1.30 FLT   10 - 1999 - FLT 6000 - 8999 
AI-AI DD  1.00 FLT  100 -  399 - FLT   10 -   99 
AI-AI DD  1.00 FLT  100 -  399 - FLT  100 -  399 
AI-AI DD  1.00 FLT  100 -  399 - FLT  900 -  999 
AI-AI DD  1.15 FLT  400 -  899 - FLT   10 -  399 
AI-AI DD  1.15 FLT  400 -  899 - FLT  900 -  999 
AI-AI DD  1.00 FLT  900 -  999 - FLT   10 -   99 
AI-AI DD  1.00 FLT  900 -  999 - FLT  100 -  399 
AI-AI DD  1.15 FLT  900 -  999 - FLT  400 -  899 
AI-AI DD  1.00 FLT  900 -  999 - FLT  900 -  999 
AI-AI DD  1.30 FLT 6000 - 8999 - FLT   10 - 1999 
AI-AI DD  1.30 FLT 6000 - 8999 - FLT 9001 - 9999 
AI-AI DD  1.30 FLT 9001 - 9999 - FLT 6000 - 8999 
AI-AI DD   .45 
AA-AA DD SUP   FLT 6000 - 9099 - FLT 6000 - 9099 
SG-SG DD  1.00 
S2-S2 DD   .30 
UK-UK DD   .40 FLT  936 - FLT  847 LKO - GOI 
UK-UK DD   .45 
6E-6E DD  1.00 
9W-9W DD   .30 
AI-S2 DD  2.00 
AI-9W DD  2.00 
S2-AI DD  2.00 
S2-9W DD   .30 
9W-AI DD  2.00 
9W-S2 DD   .30 
**-CZ DD  1.30 TRM 3  - 3  
CZ-** DD  1.30 TRM 3  - 3  
**-** DD   .45 TRM 3  - 3
```

Answer (score 4):

**If your flights are on the same ticket, technically, yes, there is enough time to make the connection**. In this case, you wouldn't have been allowed to buy the ticket if the connection time were shorter than the airline's minimum connection time for the airport. If you miss the connection due to circumstances outside your control, you'll be rebooked on a later flight at no cost.

If your flights *aren't* on the same ticket, you generally want to allow significant extra time beyond the standard minimum connection times for that airport, because you're on the hook if you miss your connection. In this case, a short layover may not be prudent even if it is technically possible.  Judging from Air India's [45 minute minimum connection time](http://www.airindia.in/delhi.htm) for domestic-to-domestic transfers in Delhi, **you'd most likely want to give yourself more than 35 minutes to connect if your flights are on separate tickets**.

Comment: Delhi's airport is also notorious for smog delays in the winter season (read: now), so 35 min is IMHO hysterically optimistic even if it's technically legal.